# Textarea box moving on click on initial page load

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea box that moves on initial click on page load. This is odd and seems a bit buggy, I do not even know where to start debugging.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Here is an image. The white box goes back to the textarea immediately and the the textarea is fine. Its only on initial load on initial click.

[image]

Here is my html

```css
  

 .textarea {
      display: block;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 24px;
    } 


.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.label {
  color: seagreen;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.form-group {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.submit {
  font-family: Chalk-c1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 43px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textarea {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}

html {
  background-color: #111;
  font-family: Chalk-c1;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Contact</div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="label">Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="input" id="name" placeholder="John Doe">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="label">Email</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="input" id="email" placeholder="john.doe@gmail.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="label">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" class="textarea" placeholder="How can we help you ... ?"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="submit">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can we get more code, jsfiddle perhaps?

Comment: I added more code. Let me know if this work

Comment: The code snippet above looks ok

Comment: @JonathanCorrin it's not showing this issue in the sample

Comment: It does. Im using a custom font-face. Could this be the issue? Im not sure what else it could be

Comment: I commented out the custom font and it still had the same issue

Comment: Can you give more specific instructions on how to reproduce this issue? Where should we be clicking to see this happen? The code above seems to look fine to me too.

Comment: I added a giph. I cant seem to get it to reproduce on the fiddle. Its using all the same code. This is an angular/node app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is because of the Grammarly plugin. Once I had this kind of issue but when I turned off that plugin, I've solved it. So just check whether this works..

Comment: Oddly enough this was my actual issue. Good to know it was only on my computer if I had grammarly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Like the other answers, I think it is because of your 3rd-party plugin.

As a workaround, you could try forcing the `position` attribute to `static` since I am guessing that's what's causing it to jump (the plugin may be changing the `position`) - Without seeing the code I don't know for sure though.

Comment: It must be. I applied that CSS and it worked. Although I now lose the placeholder. I do not care much about the placeholder. Thanks!

Comment: Actually. It also now removes my ability to type into the message box. Thats weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put this to the textarea:

```
outline: 0;
border: none;
```